# Dos campos unicos relacionados en la base de datos

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla en la base de datos compuesta por id, id_producto, id_usuario, comentario y quiero que en un mismo producto se limite los comentarios a 1 por usuario .
Por ejemplo en un producto al insertar un comentario quedaría id_producto = 1, id_user = 1, comentario = "texto" y me gustaria bloquear que este mismo usuario que no pueda dejar otro comentario en este producto pero si pueda dejar otro comentario en otro producto.

Comment: Y cual seria el problema? el sistema que ingresa los datos, verifica si ya existe un comentario y en caso de que exista, no deja ingrear otro...

Comment: Te refieres a php por ejemplo ? Pensaba que lo mejor era limitarlo tambien en la base de datos

Comment: La base de datos no sabe de reglas de negocios, y esto es claramente una regla de negocios. Podes limitarlo? si, podrias poner un indice unico por id_producto y id_user. Pero en ese caso, tu programa va a tratar de hacer un insert, y la base de datos le va a retornar un error, con lo cual tu programa va a tener que saber que hacer con el error, que es lo mismo que si tu programa controla si puede o no antes de mandarlo, porque seguramente de alguna forma ya lo sabe. La base de datos cuida y guarda datos, no maneja el negocio. El negocio, lo maneja el programa.

Comment: Y cada proximo insert va a tardar mas porque la DB va a tener que controlar contra todo su indice si existe o no. Y ademas va a ordenar ese indice. y hara otras cosas. Ojo, puede que si quieras un indice por eso para hacer busquedas, y en ese caso estaria ok. Pero si no lo necesitas, no tiene sentido crear una regla de negocio con un indice

Comment: A bien gracias, entonce podria usar un if por ejemplo pero como puedo comprobar los datos de una coleccion ? Se como comprobar si fuera un solo resultado pero tendria que comprobar todos los comentarios de "id_profile = 1" por ejemplo

Comment: ya no te entiendo, y me parece que viraste el problema hacia otro lado. comprar que cosa en donde?

Comment: Tienes razón , creo que daré por terminada esta pregunta y abriré otra gracias por tu ayuda